# Solution of a nonlinear equation

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have the following equation that I need to solve

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(\lambda-\lambda_i) = (\lambda^2+\lambda\alpha_n-\gamma_n)\prod_{i=1}^{2n-2}(\lambda-\mu_i)-(\lambda\beta_{n-1}-\delta_{n-1})\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}(\lambda^2+\lambda\alpha_i+\delta_i)
$$

The two sets $\{\lambda_1, ...,\lambda_{2n}\}, \{\mu_1, ..., \mu_{2n-2}\}$ are given and four sets $\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n\}, \{\gamma_1, ..., \gamma_{n}\}, \{\beta_1, ..., \beta_{n-1}\}, \{\delta_1, ..., \delta_{n-1}\}$ are unknown. The $\lambda$ is a variable can take any value.

To solve this equation, I equate the coefficients of $\lambda^{2n-1}, \lambda^{2n-2}, \lambda^{2n-3}$ of both sides, this ends up to the following values

\begin{align*}
\alpha_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{2n-2}\mu_i - \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\lambda_i\\
\gamma_n&= \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n}\lambda_i\lambda_j+\alpha_n \sum_{i=1}^{2n-2}\mu_i - \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n-2}\mu_i\mu_j\\
\beta_{n-1}&=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq2n}\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k+\alpha_n \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n-2}\mu_i\mu_j-\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq2n-2}\mu_i\mu_j\mu_k
\end{align*}

Now for $j=1,2,...,2n-2$ I let $\lambda = \mu_j$, then

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(\mu_j-\lambda_i) = -(\mu_j\beta_{n-1}-\delta_{n-1})\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}(\mu_j^2+\mu_j\alpha_i+\delta_i)
$$

It is a big system of nonlinear equations with $2n-1$ unknowns. I have no clear and direct way to go on. I would be appreciated for any constructive comment or idea that leads to solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are attempting something totally outlandish. The task is just to divide two polynomials with remainder and to factor the remainder as a product of one linear and a bunch of quadratic polynomials (which, of course, will require finding its complex roots, but the corresponding routines are readily available).

Comment: Forget about doing this analytically. There are efficient algorithms for polynomial division you can use to find polynomials $q,r$ in $f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$ (e.g. in Mathematica it would just be to write `q[x_]= PolynomialQuotient[f[x], g[x], x]` and `r[x_]= f[x]-g[x]q[x]`). This part can be done symbolically. To get it on the form you want you would need to locate roots of these polynomials. This will have to be done numerically.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer*: I don't have a full answer. Just some ideas.

You have already managed to get $\alpha_n$, $\gamma_n$ and $\beta_{n-1}$. So it is safe to count them as known parameters. Now let $\lambda=0$, then
$$\prod_{i=1}^{2n}\lambda_i+\gamma_n\prod_{i=1}^{2n-2}\mu_i=\delta_{n-1}\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}\delta_i=\delta_{n-1}^2\prod_{i=2}^{n-2}\delta_i$$
The left side of the above equation is known. Let's call it $p$.

In the main equation, let $\lambda=\lambda_j$ for $j=1,2,...,2n$ to get
$$(\lambda_j^2+\lambda_j\alpha_n-\gamma_n)\prod_{i=1}^{2n-2}(\lambda_j-\mu_i)=(\lambda_j\beta_{n-1}-\delta_{n-1})\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}(\lambda_j^2+\lambda_j\alpha_i+\delta_i)$$
The left sides of these $2n$ equations are also known. Let's refer to the LHS as $P(\lambda_j)$ as it is a function of $\lambda_j$. So we have a set of $2n+1$ equations:
$$\begin{align}
P(\lambda_j)&=(\lambda_j\beta_{n-1}-\delta_{n-1})\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}(\lambda_j^2+\lambda_j\alpha_i+\delta_i),\qquad j=1,...,2n\\
p&=\delta_{n-1}^2\prod_{i=2}^{n-2}\delta_i
\end{align}$$
By the way, I didn't get where $\{\gamma_1, ..., \gamma_{n-1}\}$ and $\{\beta_1, ..., \beta_{n-2}\}$ enter the equations. They seem to have no role in your problem.

Comment: With $2n+1$ equations and $2n-4$ unknowns ($\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{n-1},\delta_2,...,\delta_{n-1}$), I doubt that a general solution can be obtained  :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By solving this equation the $\beta_i$s and $\gamma_i$s be solved later, you are right, I shouldn't enter them in the question. I will read your solution and reply you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are handling a polynomial identity and using a symbolic processor with

$$
\prod _{i=1}^{2 n} \left(\lambda -\lambda _i\right)-\left(\lambda  \beta _{n-1}-\delta _{n-1}\right) \left(\prod _{i=2}^{n-1} \left(\lambda  \alpha _i-\delta _i+\lambda
   ^2\right)\right)-\left(\lambda  \alpha _n-\gamma _n+\lambda ^2\right) \left(\prod _{i=1}^{2 n-2} \left(\lambda -\mu
   _i\right)\right) = 0
$$

we can obtain the following relationships

$$
n = 1\to \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \delta _0+\gamma _1+\lambda _1 \lambda _2&=&0 \\
 \alpha _1+\beta _0+\lambda _1+\lambda _2&=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$$
n=2\to\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \delta _1+\lambda _1 \lambda _2 \lambda _3 \lambda _4+\gamma _2 \mu _1 \mu _2&=&0 \\
 \beta _1+\lambda _2 \lambda _3 \lambda _4+\lambda _1 \left(\lambda _3 \lambda _4+\lambda _2 \left(\lambda _3+\lambda
   _4\right)\right)+\alpha _2 \mu _1 \mu _2+\gamma _2 \left(\mu _1+\mu _2\right)&=&0 \\
 \gamma _2+\lambda _2 \lambda _3+\left(\lambda _2+\lambda _3\right) \lambda _4+\lambda _1 \left(\lambda _2+\lambda _3+\lambda
   _4\right)-\mu _1 \mu _2+\alpha _2 \left(\mu _1+\mu _2\right)&=&0 \\
 -\alpha _2-\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\lambda _3-\lambda _4+\mu _1+\mu _2&=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

etc.

Follows the MATHEMATICA script

```
p[n_] := Product[lambda - Subscript[lambda, i], {i, 1, 2 n}] - (lambda^2 + Subscript[alpha, n] lambda - Subscript[gamma, n]) Product[lambda - Subscript[mu, i], {i, 1, 2 n - 2}] + (lambda Subscript[beta, n - 1] - Subscript[delta, n - 1]) Product[lambda^2 + Subscript[alpha, i] lambda - Subscript[delta, i], {i, 2, n - 1}]
Thread[CoefficientList[p[1], lambda]==0] // FullSimplify
Thread[CoefficientList[p[2], lambda]==0] // FullSimplify
```

Now defining $\mathcal{P}(x,n,m)$ as the sum of all possible $m-$product combinations of the list $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$

ex. $\mathcal{P}(\lambda,3,2) = \lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3$

Now we can make some generalizations. For $n = 5$ we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
-\alpha_5 & = &\mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,1)-\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,1)\\
\gamma_5 & = & -\mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,2)+\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,2)-\alpha_5 \mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,1)\\
-\beta_4 & = & \mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,3)-\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,3)+\alpha_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,2)+\gamma_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,1)\\
-\alpha _2 \beta _4-\alpha _3 \beta _4-\alpha _4 \beta _4+\delta _4& = & -\mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,4)+\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,4)-\alpha_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,3)-\gamma_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,2)\\
\phi_4(\alpha.\beta,\delta) & = & \mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,5)-\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,5)+\alpha_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,4)+\gamma_5 \mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,3)\\
\phi_5(\alpha,\beta,\delta) & = & -\mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,6)+\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,6)-\alpha_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,5)+\gamma_5 \mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,4)\\
\phi_6(\alpha,\beta,\delta) & = & \mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,7)-\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,7)+\alpha_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,6)+\gamma_5 \mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,5)\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
-\delta _2 \delta _3 \delta _4^2 & = & -\mathcal{P}(\lambda,2n,10)-\gamma_5\mathcal{P}(\mu,2 n-2,8)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This answer assumes that the identity holds for every $n$. But I just guess (from the looks of it) that $n$ is fixed and we are dealing with a fixed number of parameters and unknowns.

Comment: I think that to elaborate relationships between $\lambda, \mu$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ the way is the polynomial identity.